# What is the reset(_:) method

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS app development, and I came across a line which confused me:

> Also add a call from `reset(_:)` so it works when you reset the app

But I can't find a `reset(_:)` function anywhere, both in ViewController and AppDelegate. Do I have to create the function, or is it something different?

Comment: Where did you find this line? Is that from `AMWorkflowController`?

Comment: Please post code where you tried this method.

Comment: @Larme I found this code in the iBook `Intro to App Development with Swift`, by Apple

Comment: On a few pages before (it's step 17.5 while your quote is from 17.6), you created `@IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject)`. That's the method it's talking about. Because you should have a "Reset button" on `ViewController.swift`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Please could you put it in an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's add the additional infos:
Your quote is from [Intro to App Development with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/intro-to-app-development-with-swift/id1118575552?mt=11), Apple's iBook., chapter `17.6 Polishing the Interface`, in `Disabling sliders` subpart.

You missed the previous part:

> `@IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject) {​}` 
> Open the Connections inspector. You’ll see that the button has been
>   connected to the Touch Up Inside event. This is the standard event
>   used ​for most buttons. Your reset button will set the value of each
>   slider to 1 and the `isOn` property of each switch to false. Add that
>   code to the new action method.

So your quote was talking about that method that you should have added previously on `ViewController.swift` in the chapter `17.5 Reset Button`.